# Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class. (In Flutter)

Tags: flutter

Flutter project is running in android but when ever I am going to run the same project for iOS using mac. It occurs this following error:

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 Pro in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                           1,809ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `exists?' for File:Class.

 #  from /Users/apple/Documents/FlutterDev/PHR_iOS-Abhishek_Roster/ios/Podfile:34
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:335:in `rescue in block in from_ruby'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:329:in `block in from_ruby'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:50:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.1/lib/cocoapods-core/podfile.rb:327:in `from_ruby'
```

I have tried to delete the podfile
clean the project
and run

But its not working